# Offset Property of Range object returns empty after first step of for loop?

Tags: excel, vba, offset

I am trying to step through a table on one of my sheets using a for loop, and then comparing the value at each of these cells with the eventVendor string.

Data Structure (on sheet in question):

Key | Vendor | Part Number | LastIns

(there are 364 rows, including the above headers)

Code:

```
Application.Goto (Sheets("SKIPLOT").Range("A1"))
totalRows = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lastEntry = Cells(2, 2)
MsgBox lastEntry.Value
For i = 0 To totalRows
    If lastEntry.Offset(i, 0).Value = eventVendor Then
    MsgBox "1st if passed"
        If lastEntry.Offset(i, 1).Value = eventPN Then
            MsgBox lastEntry.Offset(i, 1).Value
            MsgBox eventPN
            lastEntry.Offset(i, 2).Value = "NCR"
            Exit For
        End If
    End If


Next
```

The msgbox printing the lastEntry value gives the proper value, and when i = 0, the first If statement should evaluate to false, and during debugging this seems to be operating perfectly. However, when i is incremented to 1 (and beyond 1), the lastEntry.Offset(i,0).Value is showing as empty, even though the data is contiguous. All other variables contain the values I expect. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If `lastEntry` is a `Range` object, you need to `Set` it: `Set lastEntry = Cells(2, 2)`.

Comment: @BigBen Thank you, I tried this and it works as expected.

Comment: Add `Option Explicit` to the very top of the code module. This will force you to declare all variables, as I bet right now `lastEntry` is being used as a Value, which would cause the issue.